# My mac ubuntu is overheating

Tags: battery, mac, overheating

I changed my operating system on my MacBookPro11,3 to ubuntu and as soon as I did that I started having overheating issues.
As soon as I turn it on even if I just open the terminal and do pretty much nothing it starts to get hot.
It wasn’t like that with mac os.
The battery is very bad now too.
I am new to linux and I really don’t know what I should do.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: That is because MacBooks in general have terrible cooling, so Apple designs MacOS to throttle the CPU so that they stay reasonably cool (and use less battery). You can try switching to "powersave" mode and see if it's more reasonable. Otherwise maybe someone else has a solution for you.

Comment: Add your Ubuntu version and processor make and model to your question. Try disabling turbo in BIOS, or from the command line. You might also need thermald, to throttle the CPUs.

Comment: 20.04 I don’t know how to check the processor make and model.

Comment: Do: `grep -i "model name" /proc/cpuinfo`